# Subtract two data sets where column names are same

Tags: r

I have the following data frames: `df1` and `df2`. How can I subtract the two data sets(`df1 - df2`) where the column names are same?

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
a   b   c
2   4   1
3   3   12
5   3   2")

df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
c   a   b
0   1   7
4   1   8
3   2   9")
```

the resulting dataframe `df3`

```
df3

a    b   c
1   -3   1
2   -5   8
3   -6  -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write

```
df1-df2[colnames(df1)]

#   a  b  c
# 1 1 -3  1
# 2 2 -5  8
# 3 3 -6 -1
```

Comment: If the down-vote would be accompanied by an explanation, I could understand what is wrong

Comment: for the downvoter: there is nothing wrong, this answer gives the desired output